# Get sum in mysql from multiply tabels if id match?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying of get the sum of B1 and the sum of answer_value if question_id is matching. How can i add an join on my mysql query?

```
question <- table
question_id      B1
     1           1
     2           1
     3           1

 answers <-table
 question_id   answer_value
    1               2
    2               2
    3               2
```

code:

```
 select SUM(B1) from questions where B1=1

desierd results:
 answer_value    B1
      6          3
```

Comment: What are your desired results with your sample data?

Comment: Use `SELECT SUM(B1) AS B1_SUM, SUM(answer_value) AS ANSWER_SUM 
FROM question q join answer a
on q.question_id = a.question_id;` if you'd like to sum values separately. If you want to add them all you can use `SELECT SUM(B1 + answer_value) AS TOTAL
FROM question q join answer a
on q.question_id = a.question_id;`

Comment: @sgeddes i've added desierd results :)

Comment: Just use a `JOIN` as @oardic has provided and add your `WHERE` criteria: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ba61/4

Comment: @oardic thx you solved it! :) and qeddes thx for your fiddle:)